# How to shift level up voltage signal?

Tags: signal, level-shifting

[image]

I am looking for a circuit to do a level shift for a signal from R<sub>L</sub> for a DAC0808LCN.

[image]

From what I see in the image, this signal has three levels (-100, -200 and -300 mV) and a 10 kHz frequency, but I need to shift this signal by 200 mV to be (100, 0 and -100 mV). Any recommendations for doing this?

Comment: You can add a 200mV DC-Bias via Op-Amp. See https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/ax1q4g/how_to_add_dc_bias_to_opamp_output/ or https://www.k-state.edu/edl/docs/pubs/technical-resources/E-Club-Op-Amp-Lecture-Part-2.pdf

Comment: I am try that with TL082 by connected Non-inverting Summing Amplifier from https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_4.html

Comment: But output is not correct

Comment: What you'll need is a symmetrical output, consider then the circuit advised also for old DAC0800 in its datasheet https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/dac0800 (see fig.23 on PDF page 10)

Comment: DAC0808! Goodness, that takes me back. Even the datasheet refers to the 741. I feel old.

Comment: Yes LuC i need it be symmetry but for that advise use same Rload at two point right ?